# Why does the below code give 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid?

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime-error, c++14

I am getting std::logic_error' what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid when i run the function sort_string with the for loop but not with simple relational operator to compare the two strings.
The program constructs the largest number from the vector of given numbers. For small input it works fine but not for large input. I've provided the input below.

```
         #include<iostream>
         #include<string>
         #include<algorithm>
         #include<vector>

         bool sort_string(std::string x, std::string y) {

           std::string xy = x.append(y);
           std::string yx = y.append(x);


        //   For loop below, to calculate larger string gives "terminate called after throwing
        //   an instance of 'std::logic_error' what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid"
        //   Just comment the for loop and uncomment the last return statement to see


        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         for (int i = 0; i < xy.size(); i++) {

              if (xy.at(i) > yx.at(i)) return true;
              if (yx.at(i) > xy.at(i)) return false;
         }
              return true;
       //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     /*
          This runs perfectly fine
     */

         //return xy>=yx;

        }
       
        int main() {
             int n;
             std::cin >> n;
             std::vector<std::string> arr(n);
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                   std::cin>>arr[i];
             }
             std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), sort_string);
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                  std::cout << arr[i];
             }
             std::cout << std::endl;
         }
```

Instructions:
Run with g++ -std=c++14

Input:

100

2 8 2 3 6 4 1 1 10 6 3 3 6 1 3 8 4 6 1 10 8 4 10 4 1 3 2 3 2 6 1 5 2 9 8 5 10 8 7 9 6 4 2 6 3 8 8 9 8 2 9 10 3 10 7 5 7 1 7 5 1 4 7 6 1 10 5 4 8 4 2 7 8 1 1 7 4 1 1 9 8 6 5 9 9 3 7 6 3 10 8 10 7 2 5 1 1 9 9 5

Comment: The crash I get suggests your compare does not adhere to strict weak ordering.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about strict weak ordering in the compare function of sort. I get it now. One more doubt see @R Sahu comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by

```
return true;
```

in `sort_string`. It needs to be

```
return false;
```

When you reach that line, `xy` is *equal* to `yx`. Hence `yx < xy` is `false`, not `true`.

The line

```
return xy >= yx;
```

works because that line is the same as

```
return yx < xy;
```

Comment: Like @Retired Ninja pointed out it was because of strict ordering so why (return xy>=yx) is working is it because of compiler.

Comment: @dark_prince, as I pointed out in my answer, `xy >= yx` works because it is the same as `yx < xy`. It has nothing to do with the compiler. As to why it works for small size input, I don't know.

Comment: well if xy==yx then xy>=yx returns true the same as for loop but xy>yx will return false.

Comment: @dark_prince, with the detailed code, you will not reach `return false;` if `yx != xy`. Then, the function will return form inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would would work simply by changing the `return true` outside the `for loop` to `return false`. However, I fail to understand why do you complicate this code **SO** much when you could simply do

```
bool sort_string(const std::string& x, const std::string& y)
{
  return x > y;
}
```

Or even implement it as a lambda.

Comment: Yes that's what I did in the last return statement (return xy>=yx). I need to append both the strings before comparing.

Comment: Why do you need to append both strings? The elements in the vector are supposed to change?

Comment: Actually the code should return the largest number formed from the vector of given numbers if i don't append them it will just work for vector of single digits numbers. For ex: [4, 42] will sort the vector to  [42,4]  which will print 424 but i want [4,42] only means 442.

Comment: I see. Well, just an advice: you should pass values by reference like in the code I provided. Strings can be very expensive resources to copy. And instead of using x.append(y), you could simply do x + y.